# One Regular Expression

Tags: python

My question is very simple.Can someone explain this python Regular Expression for me?

`neg_pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(negations_dic.keys()) + r')\b')`

And the negations_dic is here:

`negations_dic = {"isn't":"is not", "aren't":"are not", "wasn't":"was not", "weren't":"were not"}`

I want to know what do the ( and ) and '|' mean .

This is the command that use the regular expression above:

`neg_handled = neg_pattern.sub(lambda x: negations_dic[x.group()], lower_case)`

And what is the use of `x.group` mean? Does it return the key-value pair in the `negation_dic`?

Comment: How about reading a tutorial first? Say, this one: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: Well, read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). It explains all of it in detail.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expressions:

`|` means 'or' (so any one of the choices will do), and '( )' means a matching group.

So, `'(is|are|was)'` will match any of the words `'is'`, `'are'`, or `'was'`.

**But, the question seems to be more python than regular expression to me.**

`'|'.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` will result in a matching group `'(a|b|c)'` which will match any of the elements in the list.

Comment: Well,thank you for the answer.And can you tell me something about the x.group()?

Comment: x.group() returns the matching group.
So, in your program it returns one of the keys in the negations_dic

Comment: So the keys in the negations_dic will be replaced by it's value.Wow,thank you very much to give me this guidance.

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, could you please upvote and mark this answer as correct?

Comment: I have thinked about it again.The x.group() should return one of the keys in the negations_dic rather than the keys in the negation_dic.I think this is about the function of pattern.sub()